# XML RPC Service over SSL with Basic Authentication from Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, ssl

i have to handle following setup.

i have to call an in php implemented xml-rpc service interface over ssl(basic authentication) from my spring application.

the return type of the function is a simple string.

i tried to make the call with burlap but i am getting a `CertificateException`. i think that has to do with the self signed serverside certificate. i was not able to disable the certificate validation with burlap.

what whould you use to make this function call and how would the spring configuration look like?

thanx

#### INTERFACE TO CALL

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $colourID
 * @return string colorname
 * @throws ApiException
 */
public function getColour($colourID)
```

#### ENDPOINT (ssl/basic auth)

- hxxps://api.application.com/colour
- User: ExternColour
- PW: xxxxxxxxxx

#### MY CODE

**INTERFACE**

```
public interface IColourService {

    /**
     *
     * @param string $colourID
     * @return string colorname
     * @throws ApiException
     */
    public String getColour(String colourID)
```

**CLIENTCALL**

```
public class RemoteServiceTest {

@Autowired
IColourService colourService;

@Test
public String runRemoteService(){
    return colourService.getColour("1");
}
```

}

**CONFIG**

autowiring works so i did not mention it here

```
<bean id="colourService"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.BurlapProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="hxxps://api.application.com/colour" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="my.package.IColourService " />
<!-- HOW to configure BASIC AUTH and SSL --->
</bean>
```

Comment: :-) i added some code to the inital posting above

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a stacktrace like this:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name 
matching example.com found.
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:198)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:192)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1074)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:128)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:465)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.caucho.burlap.client.BurlapProxy.invoke(BurlapProxy.java:139)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative 
DNS name matching example.com found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:193)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:77)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1053)
    ... 36 more
```

It's an usual exception from `HttpURLConnection` when the SSL certificate doesn't match to the domain.

I've not created the whole Spring environment but the following test works for me:

```
@Test
public void test7() throws Exception {
    final BurlapProxyFactory factory = 
        new NoSslCertificateCheckBurlapProxyFactory();
    final String url = "https://example.com/service";
    final Service service = (Service) factory.create(Service.class, url);

    service.getColour("5");
}
```

`NoSslCertificateCheckBurlapProxyFactory.java`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import com.caucho.burlap.client.BurlapProxyFactory;

public class NoSslCertificateCheckBurlapProxyFactory 
        extends BurlapProxyFactory {

    private final HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier;

    public NoSslCertificateCheckBurlapProxyFactory() {
        hostnameVerifier = new NoCheckHostnameVerifier();
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL url) throws IOException {
        final URLConnection connection = super.openConnection(url);

        if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            final HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = 
                (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
            httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

`NoCheckHostnameVerifier.java`:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class NoCheckHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, if I'm right you just need to change the bean class from

```
<bean id="colourService"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.BurlapProxyFactoryBean">
```

to

```
<bean id="colourService"
    class="your.package.NoSslCertificateCheckBurlapProxyFactory">
```

Configuring basic authentication should be the following (I haven't tested):

```
<property name="username" value="user1" />
<property name="password" value="pass1" />
```

References:

- [Java SSL No Subject Alternative Matched](http://jafag.blogspot.com/2008/12/java-ssl-no-subject-alternative-matched.html)